# MySQL Count from a table where condition on the last row of a related table

Tags: mysql, count

I'm new with MySQL and actually have a problem. (... and my English is poor... :D)

**The database (extract)**
I have 3 tables: *Batch*, *MainPost* and *MainPostHistory*. 
A *Batch* has 1 to x *MainPost*, and a *MainPost* has 1 to x *MainPostHistory* (kind of log).
Every tables have an auto-increment primary key. 
In addition, a *MainPostHistory* is defined by a *DateTime* and a *MainPostStatusID*.
Of course, all tables are linked by foreign key indexes.

**What I have to do**
I have to count (for each *Batch*) the number of *MainPost* having **their last** *MainPostHistory* with a *MainPostStatusID* equals to (for an example) 0.
So I have 2 parameters: the *BatchID* and the *MainPostStatusID* to check.

**What I've done**
I wrote the following query, but receive an error "**Unknown column MP.ID**" :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MainPost AS MP
WHERE (MP.BatchID = @BatchID) AND (((
    SELECT qMPH.MainPostStatusID
    FROM (
        SELECT MPH.MainPostStatusID
        FROM MainPostHistory AS MPH
        WHERE MPH.MainPostID = MP.ID
        ORDER BY MPH.DateTime DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) AS qMPH
    )) = @SearchedMainPostStatusID);
```

**What I expect**
Why this error, and how to solve it? 
And, by the way, is it the best way to do it?
Please! And thanks for reading! :-)

Comment: mysql cannot see MP.ID nested 2 levels down on sub query one level is ok and I don't see why you have 2 levels.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your answer... Yes, I understood it while reading the answer of Forpas. Thank you too! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to nest the subquery inside another one where `MP.ID` is out of scope:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MainPost AS MP
WHERE (MP.BatchID = @BatchID) AND (
        SELECT MPH.MainPostStatusID
        FROM MainPostHistory AS MPH
        WHERE MPH.MainPostID = MP.ID
        ORDER BY MPH.DateTime DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) = @SearchedMainPostStatusID;
```